# Finding univariate-roots in Julia of a function with many arguments

Tags: function, julia

Using the package *Roots* and its function *find_zero*, I am trying to solve a univariate rootfinding problem of a function that takes more than one argument. While I am a Julia-beginner, I have checked the documentation and searched on internet but cannot really figure it out.

Say, e.g. the function to find the zero in x is: *f(x)=exp(x)-x^y*.

How should I pass the y argument to the find_zero function? Would the only solution to it be with defining parameters as global (I want to avoid this for efficiency reasons)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to this problem is typically the same across any optimization problem (and across many programming languages) where you want to solve for a subset of the parameters of your function: use [anonymous functions](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/index.html#man-anonymous-functions-1). For example:

```
using Roots
f1(x,y) = exp(x) - (x^y)
f1a = (x -> f1(x, 2.0))
find_zero(f1a, 0.0)
```

where we use the anonymous function `f1a` to fix the value for `y` at `2.0`.

Note that (AFAIK) under the hood Julia is actually using globals to build the anonymous function, but if your only concern with globals is efficiency then this is not an issue since anonymous functions in Julia are carefully crafted to be just as fast as concrete functions. The core devs are so committed to this paradigm that you'll notice the primary methods of many core functions are structured around the creation of lots of fast, temporary, anonymous functions, see e.g. `findall`, `findfirst`, e.t.c.